# is it ok to edit someone's else answer, adding more info?

Tags: discussion, questions, editing

on this question [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/97232/50289)
I did not want to post an answer but I wanted to complement a different answer that I have accepted and upvoted, but I thought I would add information so that everyone could benefit and for myself too as a document.

Someone downvoted my answer and suggested me to edit the accepted answer.

Should I really do that?
What are the rules?

Comment: As long as you aren't **invalidating** the previous answer but rather are **enhancing** it, then editing to add the link would be fine IMO.

Comment: I am not sure if I agree to this, as it would not be the original answer. How much can you add to Someone else's answer? Can you `take over` someone else's answer?

Comment: Alternatively, as I was the person who asked the question, I could have added an `edit` to my own question providing the extra details I wanted to be added

Comment: Editing the link into the question would have been even worse than making it a new answer, though. If you really weren't sure about just editing it into the existing answer, you could also have left it as a comment to it. But as its own answer it doesn't really make much sense if it's ultimately just a duplicate of the other answer. What you *could* do would be fleshing out your answer to stand on its own feet without requiring the other answer for context, but as it stands, it's not really much of an answer at all.

Comment: Yes, that sounds good to me, indeed, as I just wanted to add one piece of information containing a link. I will see if an `official solution` comes up, otherwise I will do exactly that - add a comment and drop that `answer`

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but please stop putting `random words` in code blocks. It's distracting and unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to quote a very similar question i answered on [another site](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4287/1587)

> this is just me but personally i feel that unless the answer is a Community Wiki edits to answers should be limited to formatting, grammar/spelling correction and/or clarification  and the only time time i feel to add new stuff to an answer is when you're quoting relevant parts from exiting links or posting something supportive to the existing information presented in the answer (ie. [adding a manga page](https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/52341) or [episode screenshots](https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/52324)).
>
> ...
>
> if the rejected edit was incorrect and Ero Sɘnnin did want the information in the answer [they can override the rejection being the post owner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178340/could-authors-overturn-recent-community-review-decisions/295028#295028).

now i would disagree that it should be edited in there because to me it would be superfluous and infact there is a suggested edit reject reason for this

> **no improvement whatsoever**
>
> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

now i agree with [Napoleon Wilson ♦'s comment](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4560/is-it-ok-to-edit-someones-else-answer-adding-more-info#comment13874_4560) in which it would be better to either flesh out the answer more or post the link as a comment on the original answer

Comment: +1 I have removed and answer and added a comment instead, as suggested